# Is putting -able to any verb allowed?

Tags: word-usage, latin

The best way to cut it short and still convey your message is adding *-able* to any verb.

> Yeah, it's *doable* - I considered all risks, resources to be used, my endurance, budget and the like.

Also,

> *I know you cannot sleep with any disturbance around. And, I have heard that the new hostel you are shifting in has a lot of factories nearby. Will you be comfortable?* 
>   *True, but it's still sleepable!* (I know it's improper but using this to cut it short!)

**Now, the question -**

> Is putting -able to any verb allowed following any rule/s?** We have *doable, walkable, manageable,* and so on.

If we can apply *-able* to any verb, things become so easy!

Comment: [I wrote a little answer about this on ELU once.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132535/to-be-able-to-toggle-something/132541#132541)

Comment: This is an interesting question! I couldn't come up with any verb that can't be *-able*-ized, until I read @snailboat's answer on ELU. (And I got a new word, syncope, from there too.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. True and the fun is if we are allowed to *-able(ize)* the verbs, things become so easy to interpret!

Comment: This on category on Wiktionary may be useful, though I admit it does not answer your question directly: [Wiktionary link](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-able)

Comment: @K.A It's always nice to have a list. According to the list, 1,649 verbs are listed there. I tried sampling some verbs, and it reveals that *arrive+able* is not a word. However, *allowable*, which is a word, wasn't included in the list.

Comment: Isable? Beable? Goable?

Comment: Note in some cases there is only one -able option for some synonyms - `go` - `walkable`, but not `goable`, `be` - `existible`, not `beable`, `say` - `speakable`, `hear` - `audible`.

Comment: @SF. *Hearable* is not only an option but present in dictionaries ([e.g.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hearable) ). Same with [*sayable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sayable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SUPPLEMENTAL:
Laure's answer is excellent, and describes formal use of this suffix correctly: *-ble* is used with transitive verbs to express *capable or worthy of being VERBed*.

It should be noted, however, that in colloquial use—and even more in faux-colloquial writing such as advertising—there is a growing tendency to extend the suffix to intransitive verbs to express the sense *usable or suitable for VERBing*.  Your own example, *sleepable*, is just this sort of use: it means the hostel in question is *usable for sleeping* despite the nearby factories. Here's another:

> [Franz West] spent a lot of his time sitting, being on his posterior. He made sittable sculptures. He started doing this in  the mid-1980s, he started to make these things you’d sit on. [link](http://blogs.walkerart.org/visualarts/2012/08/09/sit-specific-art-darsie-alexander-on-franz-wests-sittable-sculptures/)

**Creating new *-ble* words from intransitive verbs is not currently acceptable in formal English**, but it should not be regarded as an “error”. It is a natural extension of the sense; and historically, in fact, it represents a return to the original sense of the Latin suffix *-a/ibilis*, which expressed both ability and fitness. Several fairly common words, which entered English directly from Latin, or from Latin *via* French, have the suffix in this sense: *terrible*, *horrible*, *comfortable*. I have little doubt that in another generation or two the use with intransitive verbs will again be generally acceptable.

The *-able/-ible* distinction, by the way, reflects differing Latin stems: Latin verbs ending in *-are* in the infinitive take *-able*, others take *-ible*.

Comment: You could say "the hotel is sleepable-in", because while "sleep" is intransitive, "sleep in" is transitive. That might still not be acceptable formally (by reason of novelty/unconventionality: other constructions of the same form would), but generally I don't think it would be rejected by English speakers. They might think it sounds high-faluting.

Comment: In fact, because that construction is a bit painful, you can get away with intentional incorrectness: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSEIBaYJ3Ik (25 seconds in, "they've got to be easily turn-off-and-on-able").

Answer (score 6):

It would be fairly safe to say you can add **-able** to any verb that can bear the construction "can be + past participle" (this can be said → it is sayable), or as [snailboat/plane](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/132541/12918) pointed out all transitive verbs.

**But:**

**1-**  The suffix is not always spellable as -**able**. It will be spelled  -**ible** with a few verbs whose common point is to have a Latin root.  I do not know why with some and not others, it may have something to do with the way the suffixation of the word was formed in Latin.
A few examples:
- This post is perfectible.
- Grammar rules aren't really flexible.
- A collapsible bed (although I've already met a collapsable bed).

Sometimes the -**able** and -**ible** adjectives exist alongside, usually with a nuance in meaning. In these cases the -**ible** adjective has come directly from a Latin verb that has not made its way in present day English, and the -**able** adjective is formed from the present English verb of Saxon origin.

This cake is quite *eatable* means "it tastes nice". This cake is *edible* means I haven't put any poisonous substance in it.

A *hearable* sound (rarely used, I admit) is nice to hear, an *audible* sound has a physical quality (loudness for example) that makes you can hear it.

**2-** Sometimes the root of the verb will be slightly modified:
- verbs ending in -**ate**: navigable, translatable...
- (in)comprehensible. (I can't think of any other verb ending with -hend to generalize further)

Comment: +1 Reprehensible, apprehensible. And the 'present English verb' need not be 'of Saxon origin': 'moveable' and 'mobile' both go back to latin 'movere'.

Answer (score -1):

According to the rules of StackExchange, you should put ONE question in a QA. And you have two, and both, the one in the header and in the end, are THE questions, according to you.

The answer to the question in header is: Definitely not, because some verbs take "ible" instead:

```
dirigible, foible, submersible
```

look http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ible#English

The answer to the question at the end of the text, is: there are rulES, not a rule. Again, look [wiki](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-able#English)

There suffix -able has several meanings and you can't use it automatically - you won't know which of the meanings is meant in each case. In human languages there is only one absolute and automatic rule - **there are no absolute rules**.

Comment: Is foible an adjective?

Comment: @MarkS. It was in XVI century. Now it is not, of course. But we are talking about how words appear.(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/foible)